# Google Sheets Absolute Reference for QUERY Source Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

- I have a formula that works great for my purposes, but I'm having trouble getting it to copy down the column the way I want. It's a QUERY basically that references a range from another tab and I need that range to remain static when copying the formula down. Here it is:

  =COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(Data!A2:I,"SELECT E WHERE E CONTAINS'"&A35&"' AND I = '0001'")))/$C$25
- I have tried using $ to set the absolute reference for the "Data" sheet but it still changes when copying down. Here is what I tried:

  =COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(Data!$A2:$I,"SELECT E WHERE E CONTAINS'"&A35&"' AND I = '0001'")))/$C$25

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? Thanks!

Comment: Add another `$` before `2`: `Data!$A$2:$I`. That was the only `$` you needed actually. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(INDIRECT("Data!A2:I"),
 "SELECT Col5 WHERE Col5 CONTAINS '"&A35&"' AND Col9 = '0001'")))/$C$25
```

or:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(Data!A$2:I,
 "SELECT E WHERE E CONTAINS '"&A35&"' AND I = '0001'")))/$C$25
```